# TYPO3 BE TCA type Preview Image

Tags: php, typo3, backend, content-management-system, typo3-10.x

i search for a Solution:
How can i add a Preview Image for a TCA type?

Example: I have 3 different types and would like to display a preview image for them. The same as the t3 backend layouts.

**Just like the Backend-Layout:**

[image]

Maybe there is a solution to this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is explaining it:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/Columns/Examples.html#select-drop-down-for-records-represented-by-images

This is the example code:

```
[
    'columns' => [
        'select_single_12' => [
            'label' => 'select_single_12 foreign_table selicon_field',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
                'foreign_table' => 'tx_styleguide_elements_select_single_12_foreign',
                'fieldWizard' => [
                    'selectIcons' => [
                        'disabled' => false,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

And the code for the field of the connected table is this:

```
[
   'ctrl' => [
      'title' => 'Form engine elements - select foreign single_12',
      'label' => 'fal_1',
      'selicon_field' => 'fal_1',
      // ...
   ],

   'columns' => [
      // ...
      'fal_1' => [
         'label' => 'fal_1 selicon_field',
         'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
            'fal_1',
            [
               'maxitems' => 1,
            ],
            $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['mediafile_ext']
         ),
      ],
   ],
   // ...

];
```

As you have a strange label inside your field it's not clear if you want to link to an image, to a text or even to a field that offers a combination like it's done with relations to the table sys_file by the intermediate table sys_file_ref.

So defining more precise what you need exactly might help to give you a more detailed answer. You can edit your answer to add this description.

Comment: Yes, that looks good for a start. But is there a solution without an extra file "tx_styleguide_elements_select_single_12_foreign"? An all-in-one solution.

Comment: Actually there is for every table one file. The filenames are according to the table names. So it depends on your needs, like I wrote: your details are not enough to know exactly what you need.

Comment: I have 3 different types and would like to display a preview image for them. The same as the t3 backend layouts.

Comment: So then describe exactly what you need by editing your question.

Comment: the text has been edited ;)